# The place where ColorScheme is used in LazyRow cannot respond to its update and recomposition

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I am trying custom material3 color scheme in my own application.
But I found the components in lazy row content cannot auto recomposition when color scheme changed.

Here are example:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Test() {
    var dark by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.copy(primary = if (dark) Color.Black else Color.White)
    ) {
        Column(
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
        ) {
            Button("change") {
                dark = !dark
            }
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(16.dp)
                    .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary)
            )
            LazyRow {
                items(3) {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .size(16.dp)
                            .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I changed the color scheme instance and apply it with MaterialTheme lambda.

Screenshots here
[off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4JGo.png)
[on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnWD7.png)

The lazy row item cannot change their color to latest primary color.

Versions here

- androidx-compose = "1.6.1"
- androidx-compose-material3 = "1.2.0"

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Button(
    text: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    containerColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
    contentColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
    disabledContainerColor: Color = containerColor.copy(alpha = 0.12f),
    disabledContentColor: Color = containerColor.copy(alpha = 0.38f),
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {
    val spacing = LocalSpacing.current
        Button(
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
            onClick = onClick,
            enabled = enabled,
            modifier = modifier,
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                containerColor = containerColor,
                contentColor = contentColor,
                disabledContainerColor = disabledContainerColor,
                disabledContentColor = disabledContentColor
            )
        ) {
            Text(
                text = text.uppercase()
            )
        }
}
```

Update:
I checked it again, I found the issue will only appear in material3-adaptive: ListDetailPaneScaffold component `listPane` and `detailPane` block.

androidx.compose.material3:material3-adaptive:1.0.0-alpha06

Comment: Your code is working fine for me, i am just not sure about the button implementation. When i used `Button` from `material3:1.2.0` everything is working fine. It's your custom button you are using? Can you share it's code?

Comment: @MiroslavHýbler No, it is not worked if I print the color toString as well.

Comment: I tried the same and it's working fine, can you please share code of your `Button`? It's not material3 Button, there is no method overload with string text. I think there is some problem with invoking `onClick` or something, i am sure rest of `Test` function is correct.

Comment: OK, I have updated the question content.

Comment: Sorry, It seems that the real problem is material3 alpha library: material3-adaptive, I have updated the question content again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, problem is somewhere inside `ListDetailPaneScaffold`, i think it's a bug and you should you some temporary workaround to solve this. I made two solutions, it's on you which one you will prefer:

**Solution 1: Wrap every `LazyRow` item with `MaterialTheme`**

Now i can't really explain why is recomposition working with `MaterialTheme` applied again, but it's working.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Test() {
    var dark by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val originalColorScheme = MaterialTheme.colorScheme

    val colorScheme = remember(key1 = dark) {
        originalColorScheme.copy(primary = if (dark) Color.Black else Color.White)
    }
    MaterialTheme(colorScheme = colorScheme) {
        Column(
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
        ) {

            Button("change") {
                dark = !dark
            }
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(16.dp)
                    .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary)
            )
            LazyRow {
                items(3) {
                    //Wrap every item to make sure that item will recompose
                    MaterialTheme(
                        colorScheme = colorScheme
                    ) {
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .size(16.dp)
                                .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary)
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Solution 2: Use custom provider to provide colorScheme**

Now items will be recomposed because composer knows that value of the `LocalColorScheme` provider has changed, so underlying ui using it will be recomposed

```kotlin
val LocalColorScheme = compositionLocalOf { lightColorScheme() }


@Composable
fun Test() {
    var dark by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val originalColorScheme = MaterialTheme.colorScheme

    //Change ColorScheme based on dark
    val colorScheme = remember(key1 = dark) {
        originalColorScheme.copy(primary = if (dark) Color.Black else Color.White)
    }

    MaterialTheme(colorScheme = colorScheme) {
        //Provides colors to underlying composable
        CompositionLocalProvider(
            LocalColorScheme provides colorScheme
        ) {
            Column(
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
            ) {

                Button("change") {
                    dark = !dark
                }
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(16.dp)
                        //Use LocalColorScheme instead of Material Theme
                        .background(LocalColorScheme.current.primary)
                )
                LazyRow {
                    items(3) {
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .size(16.dp)
                                //Use LocalColorScheme instead of Material Theme
                                .background(LocalColorScheme.current.primary)
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude, I used your solution and they are worked fine. The issue tell me an importance thing is that do not trust the library which is not stable especially alpha version.